# Laptop can ping and tracert, but browser, telnet doesn't work

Tags: wireless-networking, laptop, ping, browsing

Every other system on the network works fine, no changes have been made to router, and problem existed on a different network, so I don't think its an external problem. Pretty sure it's an issue with the laptop.

Pinging domain names and IPs work fine. Tracert the same.

Browsing doesn't work, telnet doesn't work.

I can access the computer via network on my desktop, but I can't access the desktop via the (broken computer) laptop.

Anyone know what might be causing this? I have the laptop in front of me now and can relay any information from it.

Could this be caused by dropping the laptop? It fell off the bed shortly before the issues started, but not immediately before. After falling off the bed, it continued to work fine for two weeks.

Comment: Run a good AV scan? What browsers have you tried? Try creating a new user and see if the problem follows

Comment: try a different browser.

Comment: It's a fresh install of windows after a reformat. Not virus and not browser.

Comment: What do you mean by "access the computer via ... my desktop?" Ping it, ssh into it, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Ping uses the ICMP protocol. Though it validates that you have significant networking fucntionality, it does not confirm that you can make a TCP connection (or a TCP connection to a specific port, like 23 (telnet) or port 80 (HTTP).  These could be blocked by a firewall.

If you can telnet to port 80 of a well-known website, but not load it with a browser, that indicates that something is wrong with the browser configuration, or that it is corrupted.

Comment: I can not telnet to port 80, or any port for that matter. It's a clean windows install, on a known working network. Any other ideas?*edit*

I said in the original question that telent didn't work. I must be doing this wrong, because I've asked this question twice, and I can't seem to get a good answer. How do I need to ask this question so that I can get to the bottom of my problem?